# Collation & Tables

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a page that has translations from English, Japanese, Korean, Chinese, to Arabic, How should I store the values so that I don't get a null value or something similar. They're all in different charsets from big5 to whatever the one for Japanese is. Should I change the table collation away from utfs-8 or have separate tables with different collations to store the characters correctly.

Yes we have a diverse campus so we need to support these different types of languages.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10005/database-behind-a-multilingual-user-interface

Comment: Thanks, not sure why this resource didn't show up.

Comment: Probably because you searched on stackoverflow, while that one is on dba.stackexchange.